# Auto Generate invoice number based on invoice number on last row

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a userform and a database file, the format of the invoice numbers(which act like unique serial numbers) in the database goes like 001/2020, 002/2020, 003/2020 and so on.
With the help of Userform_Initialize, I am auto populating the invoice field in my userform. So if last invoice is 008/2020, the invoice in form will show as 009/2020.

The code to do that is:

```
Me.txtInvoice.Value = Format(Int(Left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
```

where lastInvoice is the Invoice number in the last used row in database, and current_year is a variable in which current year is stored, and this is working fine.

The problem now is that sometimes users need to change the invoice numbers to the format xxx-A/2020, xxx-B/2020, and so on. xxx can be any number which is getting auto generated.
So when they add this A, B, C, my code stops calculating the invoice number properly.
Also they need not add the A, B, C every time. So, in database it can xxx/year or xxx-A/year and so on

What I want is to ignore xxx-A/2020, xxx-B/2020 and add one to the last invoice number that didn't have an A/B/C

Please help

Edit: The userform Initialize code is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call Reset
    Call Reset2
    Call Reset3
    Call Reset4
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim current_year As String

    current_year = FinancialYear(Date)

    Dim nwb As Workbook
    Dim lastInvoice As String

    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\username\Downloads\TestDB.xlsx")
    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))
    lastInvoice = nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, 2)
    Me.txtInvoice.Value = Format(Int(Left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    Me.shipInvoice.Value = Format(Int(Left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    Me.tbInvoice.Value = Format(Int(Left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    'Format(Int(Left(.Cells(emptyRow - 1, 2).Value, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    nwb.Save
    nwb.Close
End sub
```

Comment: Where from your code takes `lastInvoice`? From the sheet, or from a list/combo box? how do you "populating the invoice field in my userform"? After creating a new invoice, do you pass it on the last empty row of the sheet and save the active workbook and update the form control where the 'invoice field` is populated? I am not asking that from curiosity...

Comment: I have added the userform initialize code, so its checking the last invoice number from the database, adding 1 to it, and then populating it in the userform textbox, so the users can see what invoice they are working with.
Then the save button in userform will save all the entries in the next emptyrow, with the generated invoice number. They also have an edit button, which they can use to edit entries corresponding to a particular invoice number

Comment: Does your code close so named ''database" after showing the form? If yes, how to search the records in order to find the last one without extra A, B, C? I will post a piece of code to do what (I understood) you need, but it will work only if the 'databse' workbook/sheet will be open...

Comment: What I am doing right now is with userform initialize I am opening the database, then finding the last invoice number, adding 1 to it, updating it in form, and then closing it back again as you can see with nwb.Save and nwb.Close in the code

Comment: This is what I could see, that's why I said that the problem can be solved **only if the workbook remains open**. Or, to load in your form two types of last invoice in case of not the standard one. I will try adapting your code  for this last variant.

Comment: I can adapt to your solution, keeping the workbook open in background isnt a big issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the next adaptation, please:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   'your existing code...
   '......
    '......
    LastRow = nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastInvoice = nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, 2).Value

    'to be added:
    If Len(lastInvoice) > 8 Then
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If Len(nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value) = 8 Then
                lastInvoice = nwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    'your usual code follows:
    Me.txtInvoice.Value = Format(Int(left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    Me.shipInvoice.Value = Format(Int(left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    Me.tbInvoice.Value = Format(Int(left(lastInvoice, 3)) + 1, "000") & "/" & current_year
    '...............

End Sub
```

The code will search the appropriate invoice number type and chooses it.